# How to loop through all the attached images in a post, and get their url one by one

Tags: php, loop, images

On a single post page, I would like to get the url of the attached images one by one.

For example: I uploaded 5 images in my post from the dashboard. On the single page I want each of their url, like

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php first-attachment-url ?>')"></div>
<div style="background-image: url('<?php second-attachment-url ?>')"></div>
<div style="background-image: url('<?php third-attachment-url ?>')"></div>
<div style="background-image: url('<?php fourth-attachment-url ?>')"></div>
<div style="background-image: url('<?php fifth-attachment-url ?>')"></div>
```

I also need to loop through them because I want it to work regardless of the amount of the images, e.g. if I upload 2, or 10 images it should work in both cases

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the template file at the beginning or in functions.php file:

```
function get_images_attachment_url()
{
  global $post; 
  $images_urls = array();

  $images_objects = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );

  foreach ($images_objects as $image_object) {
    $images_urls[] = wp_get_attachment_url ($image_object->ID);
  } 
  return $images_urls;
}
```

When you need to call them use foreach after calling the function get_images_attachment_url():

```
$my_images_urls = get_images_attachment_url();
foreach ($my_images_urls as $url) {
?>
  <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url  ?>')"></div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it spits out  Undefined variable for images_urls, as well as images_objects.

Any idea whats the matter? **edit:** It had a few typos, but managed to fix it, didn't see them at first

Comment: I fixed my script I forget to add the $ at my_images_urls and fixed $image_objects->ID to $image_object->ID, Now I fixed it. Copy it and try now, It should work

Comment: it shows the same image (the featured one) on every div

Comment: Sorry fo the late. I fixed my code and tested it, now it works...